# Download LiveTex OR LaTeX SOFTWARE

Tags: texlive

I have to use Latex or texLIVE software for my university article, please tell me where First I have to download or install them? am not familiar with this, just being told us to use LATEX
And, another question, where its better to download poweriso?
?
and why it was written in question I have to turn VIRUS SCAN off?
and somebody said download from cd is faster way? where I have get it? we live in middle East with can easily pay to internarial products
tnx

Comment: If you're using Windows, you have two main options, TeXLive and MikTeX. Both are fine distributions.

Comment: MikTeX has been the most used on Windows whereas TeXLive has benn the typical distro of Linux, but both can be used in both OS. Just go to  [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) or [here](https://miktex.org/download) and follow the instructions for your OS. There are different options to install even for the same OS, but in brief, the easiest way today generally is download a small net installer  (a few Mb), execute it ... and be patient (the complete distros are about 4 Gb, even a partial installation will take time).

Comment: About turning virus scanning off: that is only something to try if things do not work out. And if, with TeX Live, download size is a concern, press the Advanced button and pick a smaller scheme.

Comment: thank you, before installing Texlive  should I install power ISO for windows 10? and where I have to download power ISO?

Comment: No. If you choose to download the iso then you can simply open it from File Explorer by double-clicking. If you use the net installer then there is no iso at all.